# How to optimize save to csv file over 700k rows - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, export-to-csv

I need to write over 700k lines to the csv file. The task should last less than 30 seconds, but it works 70 seconds. How can I optimize this process?

```
$users = User::all();        

    $callback = function () use ($users) {
        $fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        fputs($fh, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");

        foreach ($users as $user) {

            if ($user->writer) {
                $books = $user->books;
                foreach ($books as $book) {
                    fputcsv($fh, Arr::prepend($data, $book['name']), ';');
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Maybe you could use chunks

Comment: When you say it *should last less than 30 seconds*, any particular reason?

Comment: set_time_limit is set to 30 second, do you have any ideas how to optimize?

Comment: Do you think chunk will help you do it in less than 30 sec